# Can someone explain the process using Playstation Now directly on a TV?

Tags: playstation-now

So, [apparently](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5338/~/playstation-now-on-bravia-and-samsung-televisions) you can use PS Now directly on selected Sony Bravia & Samsung TVs without needing a PS4.

> The PlayStation™Now Beta is available on select Sony Bravia and Samsung televisions. This article provides information on supported models, accessing PS Now, and using the service. (dated 6/10/15)

Despite claiming (as it states above) that the article provides a lot of information, it really doesn't. All it really does is explain how to pair the controller with the TV.

I'm a bit dubious because I know that PSNow often downloads the game to your PS4 but this isn't possible (is it?) on the TV... but I'm hopeful about this because this could be a great, cheaper way of accessing some of the PSNow games.

This help page doesn't specify whether **all** games can be played, or just a limited selection. Knowing that it's in "Beta" makes me wonder if it's not complete. I'm assuming that you're essentially playing the game over one of their servers but this is also not explained at all.

Does anyone have any personal knowledge about using PSNow via their TV directly **without** using a PS4? If so, can you please give some detailed information (clarified below) about how this works and whether it's stable enough to warrant the cost of controllers and the PS Now membership.

- Are all PS Now games playable?
- How does gameplay work (I'm assuming it's a streaming process)?
- Is there a lot of lag waiting for data to load?
- Assuming you have "stable broadband Internet connection with 5+ mbps of bandwidth (preferably via an Ethernet cable)", is the gameplay smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlayStation Now never downloads the game. The PlayStation 4 isn't backwards compatible with the PlayStation 3, so it's not possible to do this with a PS4 either. When playing a game using PS Now the game runs on PS3 hardware hosted by Sony. The audio and video for the game is streamed over the Internet to the PS Now client, which means that the client doesn't need to be particularly powerful. It only needs to be powerful enough to decode the video in real-time. There's no technical reason for any PS Now device not to support the full catalogue of rental and subscription games.

If you can borrow a PS3 or PS4 controller from a friend then you can try out PS Now yourself for free. Sony is currently offering a [free 7 day trial](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/apps/playstationnow/cid=IP9100-CUSA01697_00-SFPROD0000000000) of the subscription service. You don't need PlayStation Plus subscription.

Note that not all games are available through the subscription service. Some games are only available by renting them. You can rent games without subscribing.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if both PS3 and PS4 controllers work? The site I linked initially mentions DualShock 3 at first but then all of the instructions are for DualShock 4 controllers.

Comment: It should work the same way. That's also you how you pair the DualShock 3  with a PS3. Just connect the controller to the device and push the PS button.